# Создание документации Swagger в помощью Symfony?

Tags: symfony3, swagger

В данной теме не силен и из-за этого прошу подсказки у кого есть опыт. В наличии Symfony 3 и есть api. Существует ли swagger бандл для данной симфони который пройдется по всем контроллерам и сделает документацию api?

аннотации к методам описаны.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html